# How to plot these errorbars of x-axis to be logarithmic with ErrorListLogLinearPlot?

Tags: plotting

```
data = {{{8.9053, 0.332061}, ErrorBar[(14.4292 - 3.3245)/2, (0.423087 - 0.241563)/2]}, {{1.49645, 0.619758}, ErrorBar[(0.788969 - 0.4541078)/2]}, {{1.310, 0.0}, ErrorBar[(1.73756 - 0.86043)/2, (0.57853 - 0.0)/1]}, {{0.89608, 0.510028}, ErrorBar[(0.579105 - 0.440952)/2]}, {{0.33885, 0.610708}, ErrorBar[(0.42503 - 0.252973)/2, (0.699667 - 0.522424)/2]}};
data2 = data /. {{{x_, y_}, 
      ErrorBar[err_, err_]} :> {{{x, y}, Around[{x, err}, {y, err}]}}};
ErrorListLogLinearPlot[data2, PlotRange -> {{0.1, 18}, {0.25, 0.75}}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Medium], PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Medium]]
```

Comment: What’s the question? What problem have you encountered?

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {{{8.9053, 0.332061}, 
    ErrorBar[(14.4292 - 3.3245)/2, (0.423087 - 0.241563)/2]}, {{1.49645, 
     0.619758}, ErrorBar[(0.788969 - 0.4541078)/2]}, {{1.310, 0.0}, 
    ErrorBar[(1.73756 - 0.86043)/2, (0.57853 - 0.0)/1]}, {{0.89608, 0.510028},
     ErrorBar[(0.579105 - 0.440952)/2]}, {{0.33885, 0.610708}, 
    ErrorBar[(0.42503 - 0.252973)/2, (0.699667 - 0.522424)/2]}};
```

None of your `ErrorBar` match the pattern `{{x_, y_}, ErrorBar[err_, err_]}`; so no replacements are made. It is unclear what you are trying to do on the RHS of the replacements. Assuming that there are separate errors for `x` and `y` when two values are given and equal errors when only one is given:

```
data2 = data /. {{{x_, y_}, ErrorBar[errx_, erry_]} :> {Around[x, errx], 
     Around[y, erry]},
   {{x_, y_}, ErrorBar[err_]} :> {Around[x, err], Around[y, err]}}
```

[image]

Once you convert to using `Around`, just use `ListLogLinearPlot`

```
ListLogLinearPlot[data2, PlotRange -> {{0.1, 18}, {0.25, 0.75}}, 
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Medium], PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Medium]]
```

[image]